# Scroll elements inside DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display items in scroll, but I want to display these when scroll is in the bottom of parent (#left-cnt) div not in window

```
<div id="left-cnt" class="col-md-8">
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 1</div>
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 2</div>
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 3</div>
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 4</div>
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 5</div>
   <div class="elements scroll">Element 6</div>
</div>
<div id="right-cnt" class="col-md-4">
</div>

var $doc = $(document);
var $win = $(window);
var itemsPerScroll = 2;

// hide everything that is out of bound
$('.scroll').filter(function(index) {
    // check if the element is visible and not scrolled. 
    // Note: if you dont let a little scroll (like leaving the element height), it won't trigger the scroll event.
    return (($(this).offset().top) > $win.height());
}).hide();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    // test if at the bottom
    if ($doc.height() - $win.height() - $(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        // show the <itemsPerScroll> (5) next hidden data tags
        $('.scroll:hidden:lt(' + itemsPerScroll + ')').show();
    }
    if ($('.scroll:last-of-type').is(":visible")) {
        $(".end-of-scroll").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are looking for... You want to scroll the div when the document is scrolled?

Comment: I want to show DIVs in scroll, but this code displays DIVs when scroll is in the bottom of windows not in parent DIVs of elements

Comment: maybe you can look at bootstrap scrollable div, something like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/ You can place divs inside of the scrollable div, if that is what you want

Comment: Have you tried setting `style="max-height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;"` on the `#left-cnt`? This will make items outside the column invisible, and the column itself will be scrollable and will have it's own scrollbar. (this does not need javascript to work)

Comment: Brainfeeder, Yes I tried but again items appear when scroll is in the end of windows, not in the end of parent div (#left-cnt).

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to move up or down

```
 function move_up() {
    document.getElementById('divElem').scrollTop += 10;
  }

  function move_down() {
    document.getElementById('divElem').scrollTop -= 10;
  }
```

You would have to find the position of the element in the DIV you want to scroll to, and set the scrollTop property.

Comment: Lakindu Gunasekara, I think that didn't work with this solution.